# Edit drop-down list when modifying in codeigniter

Tags: java, php, html, codeigniter

I have a form which records and has a drop-down list which brings data from the database to fill it out. Register well, the problem is that when pressing edit button I need to load the previously selected one in the drop-down list.

This is my sight code.

Marca Alimento: ">","") ?>

```
<option value="">Seleccione</option>
<?php
foreach($groups as $marcaAlimento)
{

    echo '<option value="'.$marcaAlimento['idmarcaAlimento'].'">'.$marcaAlimento['nombre'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to fetch the current row you're trying to edit into a variable, then in this your foreach loop, you check if the value is equal to the fetched row's column value and `echo 'selected'`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a selected value and have an array.

which is as follows:

**This are selected value and an array**

```
<?php
$selected = "Ball" ;
$arrayList  = array('Apple', 'Ball', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Elephant', 'Fish');
?>
```

**Code for view file which you want to display selected value**

```
<select>
    <?php
    foreach($arrayList as $option){
        if($selected == $option)
        {
            ?>
            <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $option;?>"><?php echo $option;?></option>
            <?php
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option;?>"><?php echo $option;?></option>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I hope this script will be usefull for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="centre_id" name="centre_id" class="form-control">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select List</option>
<?php foreach ($arrayList as $list) { ?>
<option <?php
    if ($list['id'] == $marcaAlimento['list_id']) {
        echo 'selected="selected"';
        }
    ?> value="<?php echo $list['id']; ?>">
```